# BIM-IOT integration on AutoDesk platform services

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk, aps

I want to integrate my BIM model with IOT data(available in Excel) in AutoDesk platform services and want to show some heatmaps or histogram for data I got.
I want to work on javascript but I am civil engineer I don't have knowledge of coding so how to start learning code like is I require to learn javascript in deep or some basic knowledge will helpful for me .
Or can you suggest me to learn something according to my project need

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a start, we recommend one of our [tutorials](https://tutorials.autodesk.io).

Our tutorials require some web development knowledge, mostly in the topics below:

1. Basic server development ([Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/getting-started-guide/) or [.NET](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/aspnet/hello-world-tutorial/modify)).
2. [REST API](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/01/understanding-using-rest-api/).
3. [HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp), [CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp), and [JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp).

Once you've got that covered, you can go through [Simple Viewer](https://tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/simple-viewer/) for a better understanding of model visualization.

After getting familiar with the initial workflow, will be easier to take the most out of the [Data Visualization extension](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/dataviz/v1/developers_guide/introduction/overview/).

Finally, there's the [aps-iot-extensions sample](https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-iot-extensions-demo) that will be helpful to achieve your goal once you get familiar with the concepts shared previously.